# Printing a single and specific method to a file in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a basic encryption program for a school project, and I want to have easily interchangable keys.  As it stands, I have a encryption class and a decryption class, with multiple methods.  One of those methods is the key that I want to print to a file.  Because I will be making many changes to those two classes (apart from the keys), I want to be able to print just that one method to a file.  I also need to be able to load it again.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean with "printing a method"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the output to a file, or the code of the method itself? If you mean the latter, just copy and paste into your text editor of choice.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're after - do you want to print the source code of the method to a file, or the result of calling that method with given arguments?  And are you trying to write to the file programmatically with Java, or are just looking for any functional way to achieve this?

Comment: to be honest, I am not %100 sure what I'm after either.  All I know is that I have a String array that I need exported to a text file, and it has to be able to be loaded when the program is running. The closest thing I know now is using FileOutputStream and FileInputStream

Comment: When you don't know what you're after how should we know ? ;)

Comment: @Marc Good point, but I am just looking for ideas to test with the trial and error approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use java serialization, as you commented that you have a String array to save, you could do something like this:

```
// save object to file
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/file")));
oos.writeObject(myArray); // where myArray is String[]

// load object from file
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/file")));
String[] read = (String[]) ois.readObject();
```

A working example ;), saving the arguments received with the application execution.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestSerialization {

    public static void main(final String[] array) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // save object to file
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/file")));
        oos.writeObject(array); // where myArray is String[]

        // load object from file
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/file")));
        String[] read = (String[]) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(read));
    }

}
```

Comment: Alright, that should work.  That was the route I originally was planning on going, but since I dont understand object orientated proggraming as much as I should, I didnt know if I would have to write the whole class object to a file.

Comment: -1 :Why should he serialise the whole String[] in a proprietary, not human-readable format, if he could save it to a plain-text file where he could edit and work with the file in other tools

Comment: I wouldnt care if I could mess with it in other programs.  That would actually be a bad thing, given the nature of the program.  If a user could mess with the key, then the program wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral You could do error-checking on the file if its plaintext, and could also recover some simple errors. If its propriatery like that, the user could also corrupt the file, but even in simple cases you have little to no chance to recover the error

Comment: @Spaeth you are right, he didn't point it out to be a requirement. Thats true and i have to admit that to serialise it was my first thought too. But as a programmer i think you know that requirements change, and he is far more flexible if he saves it plaintext. Securitywise, the serialised-object isnt a plus at all, and i dont see any benefits doing so, but many to do it with plaintext. I may have a different look at it because its an academic question (homework). Dont feel offended, as i understand your point, but disagree

Answer (score 0):

Serialization pointed out by user Speath is a very good approach I find.

If you want to be more selective in what you write into your files you can use simple File I/O to write into a file like follows:

Create a new file on the file system withe the FileWriter class and then initiate an I/O stream with BufferedWriter to write into this file:

```
// create a new file with specified file name
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myFile.log");

// create the IO strem on that file
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

// write a string into the IO stream
bw.out("my log entry");

// don't forget to close the stream!
bw.close();
```

The whole thing must be surrounded with a try/catch in order to catch IO Exception.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed that does.  I will probably use that for the other things that I will need to write to the file in question, while the String[] will be taken care of by user Spaeth's approach.  Thank you!!

Comment: +1, as this is the way to go. Dont serialise the whole String[], rather iterate over it and save it to a Plaintext-File. There is no reason to serialise the whole String[] to the disk.... thats a bad approach

Comment: @DanielLeschkowski I am looking for a way to import and export a key, and when I want to change that key, all I want to do is scroll through the String[] and change the values, and then be able to export it, without touching any other code.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral, you wouldnt have to touch the code being, like with the suggestion you accepted. And it isnt complicated or complex at all to do so, as you seem to think. It is ok to go that way if it fits, but you are not as flexible as with the plaintext-solution, and have no benefits in return if you just serialize.